# Swift naming conventions for ivars (properties)

Tags: swift, naming-conventions

```
class MainWindowController: NSWindowController, NSSplitViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet var splitView: NSSplitView!

override func windowDidLoad() {
  splitView.setPosition(lastSplitViewPosition, ofDividerAtIndex: 0)
}

func splitView(splitView: NSSplitView!, canCollapseSubview subview: NSView!) -> Bool {
  return subview == splitView.subviews[0] as NSView
}
```

What is the naming convention in Swift for the NSSplitView outlet? If I call it *splitView* as above it is irritating as the *splitView* in windowDidLoad is the property (I could also write it as *self.splitView*) and the one in the delegate method is the argument of *splitView:canCollapseSubview:*

Options I can think of:

- Always use *self.splitView* for the property
- Name the property differently
- Name the argument in the delegate method differently (ugly...)

Comment: Compare to UITableViewController: It has a tableView property, and all delegate methods have a tableView parameter ...

Comment: Yes, makes sense. Same for NSWindowController, NSWindowDelegate and window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The convention in Swift is to name properties and parameters as clearly as possible without worrying about this situation. Use `self.` to distinguish between them only when necessary. Apple uses this convention in the iBook *The Swift Programming Language*, especially for initializers.